# Boundary Fill algorithm..Stackoverflow error in java

Tags: java, graphics, flood-fill

I am trying to implement boundary fill algorithm in Java as a part of my assignment.
I am getting a stackoverflow error. Here's the code...

```
package fillAlgorithms;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Robot;

public class BoundaryFillAlgorithm implements FillAlgorithm {
    public void fill(int x, int y, Graphics g, Color fillColor,
            Color boundaryColor) throws AWTException {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        // reads the pixel value of pixel at x,y
        Color currentPixelColor = robot.getPixelColor(x, y);
        // if pixel is neither boundary color nor fill color
        // then fills the color
        if (!currentPixelColor.equals(boundaryColor)
                && !currentPixelColor.equals(fillColor)) {
            g.setColor(fillColor);
            g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
            // recursive call
            fill(x + 1, y, g, fillColor, boundaryColor);
            fill(x - 1, y, g, fillColor, boundaryColor);
            fill(x, y + 1, g, fillColor, boundaryColor);
            fill(x, y - 1, g, fillColor, boundaryColor);

        }

    }
}
```

And here's the calling class

```
import fillAlgorithms.BoundaryFillAlgorithm;
import graphics.Point;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

import shapes.Polygon;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FillApplet extends JApplet {
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        try {
            // Center of the coordinate system
            Point coordinateCenter = new Point(400, 400);
            Color black = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            Color red = new Color(255, 0, 0);
            Color white = new Color(255, 255, 255);
            g.setColor(red);
                    // filled applet with red color 
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
            Point vertices[] = new Point[3];
            // These vertices are with respect to the center of coordinate
            // center defined above
            vertices[0] = new Point(-5, 5);
            vertices[1] = new Point(5, 0);
            vertices[2] = new Point(0, -5);
            // Polygon class contains methods to draw polygons
            // This constructor accepts the vertices in the correct order and
            // the color of polygon
            // Fill color may be different from this color
            Polygon polygon = new Polygon(vertices, black);
            // Draw method draws the polygon after translating them into the
            // standard coordinate system of
            // having 0,0 in the top left corner
            polygon.draw(g, coordinateCenter);
            BoundaryFillAlgorithm algo = new BoundaryFillAlgorithm();
            algo.fill(400, 400, g, black, black);

        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to debug it and noticed that Robot class always gives the same color(r=16,g=16,b=32) ..even if it reaches the boundary of the polygon(triangle)
Is there a more efficient way to do this?
What's wrong with this code?

Comment: each fill call use a new `Robot` instance, that's strange

Comment: Do you have to use `Robot`? Or could you also use an image on which you paint which is then painted in the applet?

Comment: @Rainer Schwarze That's probably the main problem here. @surbhi Note that `robot.getPixelColor(x, y);` refers to **screen** coordinates - but you hardly ever know *where* on the screen your applet is shown! So the coordinates (400,400) do not make any sense. As Rainer suggested, the algorithm should probably be applied to a `BufferedImage` or so.

Comment: If you are looking for more efficient approach, read entire buffer once and put it to an array then work on this array and send result back to back buffer. Reading a pixel everytime from robot and writing 1 pixel lengths is not a good idea. 

Also I don't think a recursive function is the right approach here. You are wasting too much calls that tries to write on same pixels again and again. And you are likely get stack overflows just because you are having too much depth for big areas

Comment: @RainerSchwarze I would like something else since Robot is clearly not working

Comment: @Marco13 ..I think you are absolutely right ..That is why the loop does not break
I give parameters to AppletViewer to make the size of the applet 1000,1000
And draw a coordinate system with center 400,400 with respect to the screen coordinate system...Top left corner is 0,0
And then I draw whatever I want like a circle, a line, an ellipse, a polygon..etc..All of this is part of our course

Comment: And ... what should I say now? Have you tried using a `BufferedImage`? Or, if you may *not* use a `BufferedImage`, please give more details about the task description.

Comment: I did it using BufferedImage and Graphics2D ..Thanks @Marco13

Comment: Thanks @taytay.. I wrote everything to BufferedImage and then rendered it on the applet in the last

Comment: @Marco13 Will you please post your answer so that I can accept it as the right answer?

Comment: Although this was not really an "answer" (that is, not a solution), but only a small hint regarding the reason for this error, I added it as an answer now. Maybe others will find it with search terms like "flood fill AND robot AND getPixelColor" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `robot.getPixelColor(x, y);` refers to screen coordinates - but you hardly ever know where on the screen your applet is shown! So the coordinates (400,400) do not make any sense.

As Rainer Schwarze suggested in one of the comments, the algorithm should probably be applied to a BufferedImage.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to rethink your fill method.
Assume x = 10
fill(10, ...) then calls fill(9,...) and fill(11,...)
Which in turn then call fill(8, ...), **fill(10, ...)**, **fill(10, ...)** and fill(12, ...)

Comment: That *should* already be covered by the if-statement `if (...! currentPixelColor.equals(fillColor))` surrounding the recursive calls